# Error while sending multivalued customdata

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I am facing the following error while sending set of custom objects.

> Oct 21, 2015 7:28:38 PM
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.marshallers.ObjectSetToStringSetMarshaller
> marshall WARNING: Marshaling a set of non-String objects to a DynamoDB
> StringSet. You won't be able to read these objects back out of
> DynamoDB unless you REALLY know what you're doing: it's probably a
> bug. If you DO know what you're doing feelfree to ignore this warning,
> but consider using a custom marshaler for this instead.
>
> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: One or more parameter values
> were invalid: An string set  may not be empty (Service:
> AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
> Request ID: S61P89234SI8PE61M8I9QTG8RNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)     at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1181)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:766)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:485)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:306)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1799)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1614)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doUpdateItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:1241)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$2.executeLowLevelRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:937)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:1120)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:966)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:758)
> at .dao.impl.DeviceDaoImpl.addDevice(DeviceDaoImpl.java:57)     at
> .admin.device.service.impl.DeviceServiceImpl.addDevice(DeviceServiceImpl.java:38)

This is the code snippet from where this is happening

```
    @DynamoDBTable(tableName="Device")
public class Device extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{
private Set<AsscoiatedReviewer> asscoiatedReviewers ;
// getters setter

    public Device addDevice(Device device) {
        device.setDeviceId(generateId());
        device.setCreatedTime(getCurrentTime());
        if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(device.getPincode())) {
            // get lat and long - do this for review team as well
            //TODO : move it to common place that can be accessed for review team too
            setLatLong(device);
            // calculate the distances between this organization and reviewers
            calculateAsscoiatedReviewersDistances(device);
        }
        mapper.save(device);
        Device device1 = mapper.load(Device.class, device.getDeviceId());


        return device1;
    }

    private void calculateAsscoiatedReviewersDistances(Device device)  {
        if(StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(device.getPincode())) return;
        try {
            List<ReviewTeam> ReviewTeam = reviewTeamDao.getAllReviewTeams();
            Set<AsscoiatedReviewer> asscoiatedReviewers = new HashSet<AsscoiatedReviewer>();
            /*for (ReviewTeam reviewTeam2 : ReviewTeam) {
                if(StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(reviewTeam2.getPincode())) continue;
                AsscoiatedReviewer asscoiatedReviewer = new AsscoiatedReviewer();
                asscoiatedReviewer.setReviewTeamId(reviewTeam2.getReviewTeamId());
                double distance = distance(new Double(device.getLat()), new Double(device.getLongt()),
                        new Double(reviewTeam2.getLat()), new Double(reviewTeam2.getLongt()));
                asscoiatedReviewer.setDistance(new Double(distance).toString());
                asscoiatedReviewers.add(asscoiatedReviewer);
            }*/
            device.setAsscoiatedReviewers(asscoiatedReviewers);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public class AsscoiatedReviewer implements Serializable,Comparable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1906388056843006046L;

    private String distance;
    private String reviewTeamId;
// getters setters 
}
```

it seems the error is happening from the following line
device.setAsscoiatedReviewers(asscoiatedReviewers);

Should this be marshalled / demarshalled and send to amazon ? Any help would be greatly appreciated .

UPDATE :
i am getting the following exception when the data is populated in asscoiatedReviewers

> WARNING: Marshaling a set of non-String objects to a DynamoDB
> StringSet. You won't be able to read these objects back out of
> DynamoDB unless you REALLY know what you're doing: it's probably a
> bug. If you DO know what you're doing feelfree to ignore this warning,
> but consider using a custom marshaler for this instead.
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException:
> Cannot unmarshall to type class
> in.forus.foruscare.entity.AsscoiatedReviewer without a custom
> marshaler or @DynamoDBDocument annotation.    at
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.getObjectUnmarshaller(ConversionSchemas.java:590)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.augment(ConversionSchemas.java:497)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.getMemberUnmarshaller(ConversionSchemas.java:466)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.getObjectSetUnmarshaller(ConversionSchemas.java:520)

does this mean i needed to write custom marshaller or annoate with DynamoDBDocument annotation . If yes, this is set of custom objects, can you send me the pointer to simple example of marshaller. i happened to look at other marshllers, they didnt seem to explain what i need

Comment: Update : i may need to use the marshalling mentioned here , can someone please confirm  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaArbitraryDataMappingHLAPI.html

Comment: I think the value you are trying to store is empty, which you should not store in string-set

Comment: @Harshul, setting this to null or populate whenever the data is available - will work ?

Comment: When it is null just don't add that column

Comment: i am getting the following exception when the data is populated